# Undefined type 'PDF' in Laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel-8

I have done `composer require barryvdh/laravel-dompdf` and `php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Barryvdh\DomPDF\ServiceProvider"` after installing the DomPDF package.

I called to `use PDF`;

```
$pdf = PDF::loadHTML($html);

// Set the paper size (optional)
$pdf->setPaper('A4', 'portrait');

// Download the PDF with a specific file name
return $pdf->stream('sample.pdf')
```

All that to received, also aliases the package as `'PDF' => Barryvdh\DomPDF\Facade::class`

> Undefined type 'PDF'

What could be wrong, thanks.

Comment: Can you please show your alias config?

Comment: 'PDF' => Barryvdh\DomPDF\Facade::class,

Comment: Next time, [edit] your question with that information.  That said, according to the documentation, that's the wrong class.  It should be `Barryvdh\DomPDF\Facade\Pdf::class`.  This is because `Facade` is not a class under the src folder.  Facade itself is a folder, not a file.

Comment: Thanks Daedalus for your answer, I have made that change on the alias. However when I call  use Barryvdh\DomPDF\Facade as PDF;  I am getting the same issue. What could be?

Comment: As I said, there is no Facade class.  You didn't use my suggestion.

Comment: Even when I call the PDF class with use PDF; the issue still... and not Barryvdh\DomPDF\Facade as PDF

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the [documentation details](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-dompdf#using), you must either `use`, or alias: `Barryvdh\DomPDF\Facade\Pdf`:

```php
use Barryvdh\DomPDF\Facade\Pdf as PDF;
// Or, depending on personal preference:
use Barryvdh\DomPDF\Facade\Pdf;
```

Or

```
'PDF' => Barryvdh\DomPDF\Facade\Pdf::class
```

and then,

```
use PDF;
```

As is seen when you check out the repository itself, documentation aside, [the Facade portion of the namespace is a folder](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-dompdf/tree/master/src), and not a File/Class.

You cannot `use` or reference a class that does not exist.  There is no Facade class; the class you need to use, be it for alias or the regular use statement, is [`Barryvdh\DomPDF\Facade\Pdf`](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-dompdf/blob/master/src/Facade/Pdf.php).